# Resetting reset to zero after one clock cycle in verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm having trouble setting the Start(reset) to zero after being high for one clock edge. I've searched online and tried different ways of writing the clock, but what is puzzling to me is that when I set Start as 1, the clock does not toggle like it should. It is as if Start being high is blocking the execution of the clock code. Here it is:

```
initial begin
    Clock = 0;
    Start = 1'b1;
    forever begin
    #20 Clock = ~Clock;
    end
end

initial begin
    @(negedge Clock);
    Start = 1'b0;
    @(negedge Start);
    X = 3'd5;
end
```

My output waveform will look like that this:

[image: img2]

Then, if I set the code to be as such:

```
initial begin
    Clock = 0;
    Start = 1'b1;
    #20
    Start = 1'b0;
    forever begin
    #20 Clock = ~Clock;
    end
end

initial begin
    @(negedge Start);
     X = 3'd5;
end
```

I'll get the output waveform in the pic below. I don't want that though. I want the clock to be doing its normal pulses independently of Start changing. How do I achieve that?

[image: img1]

Comment: You have two `initial` blocks.

Comment: I only see one picture.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to include both pictures in the post. One was just in a link under the number 2 but it is edited now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are trying to do something like below. Note the `#1` for guarding against the negedge Clock from x to 0 at time 0.

```
initial begin
  Clock = 1'b0;
  forever begin
    #20 Clock = ~Clock;
  end
end

initial begin
  Start = 1'b1;
  #1; // little delay so x->0 transition does not trigger negedge Clock
  @(negedge Clock);
  Start = 1'b0;
  // @(negedge Start); // not needed as we know Start fell
  X = 3'd5;
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It seems that after running synthesis my test bench worked just fine. But thanks anyway! What's the difference between running synthesis and behavioral simulation?

Comment: You don't normally synthesize a test-bench. Most test-benches use non-synthesizable code; ex: `#` delays, `wait` statements, `while` loops, `forever` blocks, `fork`-`join`, etc. Synthesizable code is a subset of features and specific coding styles compared to the score of everything available in Verilog.

Comment: Oh I didn't synthesize the test-bench. I synthesized my verilog module. And somehow that helped resolve the clocking issue